# Association or usage-arrow between class and use-case?

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case, modeling

I have the following use-case diagram:

[image]

I want to say, that the actor can execute a use-case calle "add two numbers". When this use-case is executed, two instances of the class "Number" are involved. Is this represented in the diagram above?

What is the difference when I use usage-arrows like here:

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge, you should not include classes in the use-case diagram. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @vainolo good remark, that's part of my question, too! I'm looking for a way to say that a class (e.g. Number) is involved in an use-case. So, e.g. the use-case "add two numbers" will use or need two instances of Number. That's what I want to say. But I'm not sure whether a use-case diagram is the right way to do this. Have you any better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cases should be used to show how the user interacts with the system.

Use a sequence diagram to show what the use case does and there you can put the classes that act in the use case